# How to bind from DataGridColumn.Header to ViewModel property?

Tags: wpf

I want to bind my datagrid header to a property on the DataContext of the grid. Now, I got it to work, but I consider this a temporarily solution:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Description}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=DataContext.ItemsUnit}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

The biggest issue with this solution is that it makes the binding more fragile (context sensitive). If the DataContext of the grid is used in a master/detail scenario (which makes the DataContext a BindingList instead of a single item) I would have to replace update the DataGrid DataContext with `DataContext={Binding /}`.

Is there a more robust way to bind from the DataGrid.HeaderTemplate than using ElementName and refering to the DataContext?

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to use a named resource

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <MyNamespace:MyHeaderProvider x:Key="MyHeaderProvider">
  </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

Header="{Binding Path=HeaderText, Source={StaticResource MyHeaderProvider}"
```

If everything is really dynamic this may not work.  When I made a grid with more dynamic/data driven columns I did not define them in XAML but generated them in the code behind, where you don't have to do relative DataContext.

Comment: How does this work? The information in the headers is obtained from properties on the ViewModel (which is bound to the Grid DataContext), noe from a static source (like a header information provider)

Comment: where do you create the Grid's DataContext though?  
the alternative i mentioned (creating the column definitions in the CS file, not XAML) might be better for you.

Comment: here are two decent resources about doing dynamic column creation: http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/08/silverlight-datagrid-populate-dynamic-columns-from-a-child-collection/ AND http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Defining-Silverlight-DataGrid-Columns-at-Runtime.aspx